# Delete or reset a browser cookie via Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

HTML links:

`<a href="javascript:del_cookie(name);">Logout</a>`
`<a href="javascript:delete_cookie(rememberKeepMeLoggedIn);">Logout</a>`
`<a href="javascript:eraseCookie(name);">Logout</a>`

`<a href="#" onclick="del_cookie(name);">Logout</a>`
`<a href="#" onclick="delete_cookie(rememberKeepMeLoggedIn);">Logout</a>`
`<a href="#" onclick="eraseCookie(name);">Logout</a>`

Javascript:

> function delete_cookie(rememberKeepMeLoggedIn) {
>     var cookie_date = new Date ( );
>     cookie_date.setTime ( cookie_date.getTime() - 1 );
>     document.cookie = rememberKeepMeLoggedIn += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
>   }
>
> function del_cookie(name) { 
>   document.cookie = 'acceptsCookies=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;'; 
>  window.location = "http://www.smugmug.com/logout.mg?goTo=#"
>  
>   }
>
> function eraseCookie(name) { 
>   var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
>   for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
>   eraseCookies(cookies[i].split("=")[0]);
>   }

How can I delete or reset a cookie with the name "`UP-759283`"?
Does the syntax below look good?

Here's my javascript function:

> function del_cookie() { 
>   document.cookie = UP-759283 +'=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;'; 
>   }

The HTML URL callout
`<a href="javascript:del_cookie(); document.location.reload( );">Logout</a>`

Answer (score 3):

> Does the syntax below look good?

No; just run your code through [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) and you'll see. Change

```
document.cookie = UP-759283 +'=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

to

```
document.cookie = 'UP-759283=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

As per the [MDC `document.cookie` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.cookie), cookies are deleted by setting the expiration time to zero:

```
document.cookie = 'UP-759283=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;';
```

Other reference: [cookies @ quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)
.

Comment: useless string concatenation is useless. Also what if the local machine time is set to 1965 ?

Comment: @Raynos: set your machine time to 1965 and [try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/mJLZj/). On Windows 7, I can't set the system clock earlier than January 1st, 1980.

Comment: @MattBall I have to learn how cookies work >_>. I assume your answer will work though. So much code would break if you set your system clock to 1965 anyway.

Comment: No luck so far guys... any other suggestions?

Comment: @detonate: what's the problem? Did you see the demo? http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/mJLZj/

Comment: @detonate: mind walking me through exactly what I need to do with that page to reproduce the error? For starters, it looks like you're misusing inline javascript in the `<a href="javascript:del_cookie(name);">`. That should be `<a onclick="del_cookie(name);>` instead. Also, the `name` variable is `''` (the empty string) - is that right?

Comment: Matt, let me add the latest edits at the top of this thread. I'm trying to clear all the cookies when a user previously logged in